# Retriving selected checkbox values in a listbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I have a listbox binded to a list of string and with checkboxes. It supports multiple selection. After selecting the values in checkbox i want to store them  in a list of strings .

The code below throws an exception saying null argument.

XAML code :-

```
<ListBox x:Name="suites" Margin="0,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding suitelist}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>                    
                <CheckBox x:Name="check_suite" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  
                          Content="{Binding .}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource=
                          {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                          Path=IsSelected}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

C# code :-

```
suites.ItemsSource = suitelist;
suites.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
foreach (var i in suites.SelectedItems)
{
    suiteIdlist.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: At what line you getting the exception?

Comment: Can we see the exact text of the exception?

Comment: Also user2714823 you should work on your acceptance ratio here at SO, if you wan't anything from this community. 23 questions and no single accepted answer. None of the questions has valid answer for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely from the code you posted here, it's possible that `suiteIdlist` is not initialized. Initialize the list before using it:

```
suiteIdlist = new List<string>();
foreach (var i in suites.SelectedItems)
{
   suiteIdlist.Add(i.ToString());
}
```